# According to Catholicism do priests ever receive spiritual graces on account of changes in discipline?

Tags: catholicism

Can the actions of the Pope in changing sacramental discipline result in clerics having spiritual ability to read souls?

(This was brought up as a a theory in a chat in relation to a different topic).

Comment: Can you link the chat session?

Comment: @KenGraham It's subject is the conscience of man on "subjective culpabality" on Amoris L., as No Priest have faculties to see the conscience of men. That's why Pope Francis implore all priest and bishops to seek conversion, because a converted heart are docile to the voice of the Holy Spirit and can receive the gift of discernment needed for Pastoral Accompaniment. The question is wrong when it relates discernment to changes in sacramental discipline, it is a clear error.

Comment: @marianagustin Please allow the OP to respond. After all it is his question, not yours.

Comment: @KenGraham https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103004/discussion-between-eques-and-marian-agustin